# Simple SQL UPDATE works in Console but not as Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, sql-update

I know this is a very simple SQL routine, so I am confused as why it does not actually UPDATE.

These work perfectly on their own:

```
UPDATE ourwebsite.dbo.dealer 
SET Active = 0
WHERE  dealercode = 12345

UPDATE ourwebsite.dbo.reps 
SET username = username + '_LR-3.0'
WHERE  dealercode = 12345
```

But when I try to make them into a Stored Procedure, they seem ok and execute ok, but nothing updates.

```
@DealerCode VARCHAR
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;
UPDATE ourwebsite.dbo.dealer 
SET Active = 0
WHERE  DealerCode = @DealerCode

UPDATE ourwebsite.dbo.reps 
SET username = username + '_LR-3.0'
WHERE  DealerCode = @DealerCode 
END TRY
```

I am sure I must be missing something?

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: Remove the END TRY and also best to add a length when declaring a varchar  i.e.  varchar(50)

Comment: what is the data type for `DealerCode` ? Also enclosed the `Stored Procedure` query inside `BEGIN ... END`

Comment: Please post the full proc if you want it debugged. Definitely remove any `TRY CATCH`  to see if you're catching an error but not reporting it. You should probably also post the script that you use to call it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not specified length for your parameter

```
@DealerCode VARCHAR
```

so by default, it takes as VARCHAR(1). You can print or select  @DealerCode in your procedure to check the same.

Answer (score 0):

from you query

```
UPDATE ourwebsite.dbo.dealer 
SET Active = 0
WHERE  dealercode = 12345

UPDATE ourwebsite.dbo.reps 
SET username = username + '_LR-3.0'
WHERE  dealercode = 12345
```

I assumed that dealercode type is numeric because you didn't put ('...') on 12345, you could try this query that i made some bit modification on it

```
AS @DealerCode NUMERIC

BEGIN TRANSACTION

BEGIN TRY  
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    UPDATE ourwebsite.dbo.dealer 
    SET Active = 0
    WHERE  DealerCode = @DealerCode

    UPDATE ourwebsite.dbo.reps 
    SET username = username + '_LR-3.0'
    WHERE  DealerCode = @DealerCode 

    -- Commit the updates into the table
    COMMIT TRANSACTION

END TRY  
BEGIN CATCH  

    -- Execute rollback upon error retrieval routine.  
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION 

END CATCH;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard without seeing your entire procedure, as there is an `END TRY` at the bottom with no `BEGIN TRY`, so your statements might not even be executed because the execution jumps to the `CATCH`. Also make sure you are not starting a transaction without committing it.

Aside from that, there is a difference between your manual query and your procedure which is the `@DealerCode` data type. In your manual query is an `INT` (or numeric) while in your SP it's a `VARCHAR` of undeclared length. Check which data type is your `dealercode` column from your `ourwebsite.dbo.reps` table and make sure your variable is the same type. Also always indicate the length of your `VARCHAR` fields.

Test the following code and it *will* update your records, as it's the same as your stand-alone query:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.TestUpdate
    @dealercode INT
AS
BEGIN

    UPDATE ourwebsite.dbo.dealer 
    SET Active = 0
    WHERE  dealercode = @dealercode

    UPDATE ourwebsite.dbo.reps 
    SET username = username + '_LR-3.0'
    WHERE  dealercode = @dealercode

END
```

If this works, either remove your `BEGIN TRY` ... `END TRY` and your entire `CATCH` to see exactly the error you are getting, or make sure you do a `RAISERROR` on your catch with the corresponding `ERROR_MESSAGE()`. Example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.YourProcedure
    @dealercode VARCHAR(20)
AS
BEGIN

    BEGIN TRY

        -- Your operations here
        SELECT 1 / 0

    END TRY

    BEGIN CATCH

        DECLARE @v_ErrorMessage VARCHAR(MAX) = CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), ERROR_MESSAGE())

        -- Rollback if you have to

        RAISERROR (@v_ErrorMessage, 16, 1)

    END CATCH

END
```